# ERROR Kettle- Json Input and Javascript parse returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, pentaho, kettle

I am using this script in the JAVASCRIPT parse step, given a JSON Input step(text) called JIRA_FIELDS. The problem is that some field will return a value, and others (that look like embedded arrays) will return [object Object] as the value of the field. How can I Fix this?

Javascript:

```
idx = getInputRowMeta().size();

Employee = eval("("+JIRA_Fields+")");

for (field in Employee) {

    row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
    row[idx] = field;
    row[idx + 1] = Employee[field];
    putRow(row);
}


trans_Status = SKIP_TRANSFORMATION;
```

Comment: Thanks in advance to providing a solution- I am new to Javascript and Kettle and jsut trying to figure things out.

Comment: hard to say without seeing an example of your data. what do you want to happen if the field is an array, and what is it usually? A string? A number?

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to output is an object. When Javascript tries to output an object as a string it simply does [object Object]. Wrap it inside  JSON.stringify to make it a readable string

example:

```
console.log({attr: 'value'}); // -> outputs [object Object]
console.log(JSON.stringify({attr: 'value'}); // -> outputs "{attr: 'value'}"
```